# Submit data in PHP using hidden fields or query string parameters

Tags: php, submit

I'm looking for the best way to submit form parameters in PHP.

Send parameters in the URL:

```
<form method="post" 
      class="form-validate-jquery" 
      action="suppliers_sql.inc.php?a=edit_ctt&ctt_id=<? echo $supplier_contact_id ?>"
>
</form>
```

Send parameters in `hidden` fields:

```
<form method="post" class="form-validate-jquery" action="suppliers_sql.inc.php">                                        
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="edit_ctt" />
<input type="hidden" name="supplier_contact_id" value="<? echo $supplier_contact_id ?>" />
</form>
```

Which one is best?

Comment: its nothing wrong to both method, but it depends on what issue you want to tackle.. though on your case, i would go with url query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It much depends on the situation and both approaches are valid.

Personally I prefer to use hidden fields if possible, because of several reasons:

- GET parameters have limited length, although that may not be a problem for you right now...
- If you ever want to make those fields visible, migration should be a bit easier...
- If you have some sort of validation in place for form fields, applying that validation to the hidden fields should be simpler...
- It just looks a bit cleaner and easier to read...